# Where can I view mappings between AWS resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Previously, I saw a mapping table between resources within AWS. 
For example, a simple table had 4 columns

AWS Service, Resource Type Value, Relationship, Related Resource

- X ***is contained in*** Y
- X ***is associated with*** C
- V ***contains*** R

Something like this. Where is this mapping table located? I saw a web page hosted by AWS at least a week ago with this simplified relationship mapping.

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party products that can provide visualization of your AWS resources.

The closest capability of this *within* AWS is the **AWS Config** service. It can show the **relationships** between resources, such as:

- Instance is in Subnet X
- Navigate to Subnet X
- View all instances in the subnet
- View security groups associated with an instance

[image: AWS Config relationships]

It can also show the history of the resource (eg start, stop, configuration changes).

Comment: I am 100% certain I saw a page ( not within an account in console, rather public aws docs) which showed resource types and relationships. Specially a three or so column mapping. General entity mappings. It wasn’t a dream, I swear

Answer (score 0):

Located here

**AWS Config Supported Resource Types and Resource Relationships**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/resource-config-reference.html

[image]